# Sequences and Series Grade 10

Tags: sequences-and-series

The teacher put up something on the board today that I don't understand.

$$T_n = 1, T_{n+1} = 3T_n \text{ for } n \geq 1$$

Can someone please explain the question to me. I'll work out the answer once I understand the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if $n=1$ for example, then $T_{2} = T_{1+1} = 3T_{1} = 3$. Try calculating $T_{n}$ for some small values of $n$ and see if you can notice a pattern.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the teacher's material means in words.

You are describing a sequence of numbers. The first number is $1$. Each number is $3$ times the previous number.

That means the sequence starts
$$1, 3, 9, 27, \ldots
$$

You haven't told us what the question is.

Comment: That's all the teacher wrote on the board and we had to copy it down. What I didn't understand was the T$_n$ = 1 part. What I understood from it is that the nth term is 1 not the first. Clearly I understood that part wrong.